# How to pass data from Java class to a JSP page

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I am a newbie in JSP and Dynamic web projects. My project structure is shown as below. 
Basically, I am having a variable temperature in my SparkStreaming class which is generated in every 2 seconds and I wish to pass this value to the A.JSP page . 
I shall be generating few charts based on the JSP page.

How can I achieve this in Java?[image]

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23464968/passing-value-to-a-jsp-page-from-a-java-class-using-dao

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use sessions.

think in java class you have string variable call `temperature`.

```
string temperature = "11.11";
request.removeAttribute("temp");
request.setAttribute("temp", temperature);
```

in `removeAttribute` you clear the session stored value.then you set value to session.

In JSP u can access session value like this.

```
request.getAttribute("temp");
```

- **If you want to pass two dimensional array you can convert the session
  and pass the value to session**

Answer (score 0):

You should have a servlet and then call that servlet in jsp to get the latest values of temperature.